# Entering multiple lines in textAreaInput R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create an R Shiny app that takes multiple lines of input and gives the output. Particularly, I would like the input to respect when I enter a new line. For example, the syntax I would like to enter into the text input is:

```
visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9
```

I am able to enter one line and get results. For example, if I enter this it is working fine.

```
visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3
```

The issue is that I am unable to get results when I enter multiple lines. The syntax for this package requires that new equations must take the next line.

Here's the code for the shiny app.

```
library(shiny)
library(lavaan)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Text Input"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textAreaInput(inputId = "text1", 
                      label = "Syntax"), 
                      value = "Enter formula"),
        mainPanel(
           verbatimTextOutput("text1"),
           verbatimTextOutput("regout")
        )
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  formula <- reactive({
    tryCatch({
      as.formula(input$text1)
    }, error = function(e) NULL)
  })
 
  model <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(formula()))
    tryCatch({
        cfa(formula(), data = HolzingerSwineford1939)
      }, error = function(e) NULL)
    })
  
  results <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(model())){
      summary(model(), fit.measures = TRUE)
    }
  }) 
    
    output$regout <- renderPrint({
      results()
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Are you sure this `as.formula()` part works? I get a big ol' warning when running the code with a single line: "Warning: invalid formula "visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3": assignment is deprecated" and "lavaan::lavaan(model = formula(), data = HolzingerSwineford1939,  :
  lavaan WARNING: model seems to be a formula; please enclose the model syntax between quotes". How exactly do you want to display the results of several models?

Comment: I think you're right. I should try to remove the formula. I was ignoring the errors. To answer your question, I want the results to be displayed together. Typically these equations are part of one giant model.

Comment: If you just use `formula <- reactive({input$text1})` then you can paste those three lines in and they work just fine. Those three lines are not a formula so the `as.formula()` part was messing it up.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!